# com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService crashes on expanding save panel

Tags: macos

I have an application that has been around for many years. It is mainly Obj-C++, and uses the `NSDocument` architecture. At least on macOS Ventura (currently 13.6), I get a crash in `com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService` when the file chooser is requested by clicking the `^` button next to the folder popup button (i.e. expanding the save panel from the minimal version).

When it crashes, there are messages in the console:

```
CLIENT ERROR: remote view delegate  should have but lacks method which can react to a surprise invalidation
```

appears twice, then

```
WARNING: assertion failed: '<private>' in -[NSRemoteView serviceMarshalConnection] on line 4,401 of file /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/d9889869-120b-11ee-b796-7a03568b17ac/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ViewBridge/NSRemoteView.m
```

The crash logs starts like this:

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001a71d8728

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process:   exc handler [10150]

Application Specific Backtrace 0:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a3d4b104 __exceptionPreprocess + 176
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001a3869fd0 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a3d74350 _CFBundleGetValueForInfoKey + 0
3   ViewBridge                          0x00000001ab6fe5b0 -[NSViewServiceMarshal addChildWindow:ordered:] + 604
4   ViewBridge                          0x00000001ab6f6948 -[NSWindow(ViewBridgeSwizzle) swizzledAddChildWindow:ordered:] + 92
5   AppKit                              0x00000001a78d5f4c -[NSWindow(NSLayoutConstraintVisualization) _updateConstraintVisualization] + 272
```

It seems to be looking for a delegate of some sort, but implementing all the methods in the `NSOpenSavePanelDelegate` protocol shows none of them being called.

My application does not directly call any of the save panel methods, but relies on the default implementations of `NSDocument` to handle these things.

Searching for these error messages has got me nowhere. Where can I look to find out what is going wrong?

Comment: Nothing heard here... It does appear to be something in my user account that causes it. It works fine in a new account, and adding all the things I see in the login items for the real account to the new one doesn't make it fail. So there is most likely something old there that causes the problem. Any tips on where to look and tests that might help?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be that I had a line which set, for debug builds, in user defaults a true value for the key `NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints`. Removing this seems to have solved the issue.